# How can I change the splash screen for a standalone game in Unity3D?

Tags: unity

I want to change the normal Unity splash screen to be customized for my game and every time I change the splash image in the player setting it does not appear. So how can I do that please?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you don't have unity pro?

If you want custom splash screens for IOS you also need IOS pro.

Check out the licenses page: 
http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses

Comment: Thanks Mr.brandon for your reply, when I have used a licence no splash screen appeared even unity splash screen so what should I do please ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no splash screen built in for Unity standalone PC/Mac builds.  You can change the banner on the config dialog.  (See here http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-PlayerSettings.html).

If you want a splash screen when the game starts after the config dialog happens you'll have to do it yourself.  It's pretty easy, just put the image on a quad and make the camera so it sees the whole thing.  You can do fading in/out with lerping the shader color over time, or something similar to that.