# Can I remove Unreal Engine Splash Screen and put my own?

Tags: unreal-4

In Unity, I can change the splash screen if I buy the Pro version.

Can I do the same with Unreal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the splash screen for a standalone game in Unity3D?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22485/how-can-i-change-the-splash-screen-for-a-standalone-game-in-unity3d)

Comment: Use google man. This question is asked and answered already in numerous places.

Comment: No @Almo, this is not a duplicate as this is about Unreal and not Unity. Also, a question being answerable by googling does not mean it shouldn't be on this site.

Comment: Ok, then this one. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72087/can-i-legally-remove-the-default-unity-splash-screen-by-removing-it-from-the-apk

Comment: Nope, @Almo *this* question is about unreal, not about Unity

Comment: Hahaha they both start with U. Shocking this is not a duplicate. Still, if you hover over the vote buttons, they talk about "research effort" which this clearly does not show.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.unrealengine.com/eula

Check section on attribution. It appears you do not have to show the Unreal logo at startup, just mention you used the engine in the credits.

> 11. Proprietary Notices and Attribution
>
> You agree to retain and reproduce in all copies of the Licensed
>   Technology the copyright, trademark, and other proprietary notices and
>   disclaimers of Epic and third parties as they appear in the Engine
>   Code and the Content.
>
> You agree to place the following notices in the credits for any
>   Product (replacing xxxx with the current year):
>
> "[Product name] uses the Unreal® Engine. Unreal® is a trademark or
>   registered trademark of Epic Games, Inc. in the United States of
>   America and elsewhere"
>
> "Unreal® Engine, Copyright 1998 - xxxx, Epic Games, Inc. All rights
>   reserved."
>
> No other license or right in the Epic Trademarks is granted under this
>   Agreement. All use of the Epic Trademarks will inure to the sole
>   benefit of Epic. You agree not to engage in any activity that could
>   tarnish, dilute, or affect the validity or enforceability of the Epic
>   Trademarks or cause consumer confusion or diminish any goodwill
>   relating to any Epic Trademarks. If you wish to make further use of
>   the Epic Trademarks, please go to
>   https://www.unrealengine.com/branding-guidelines-and-trademark-usage.
>
> Epic may use your trademarks, service marks, trade names, and logos
>   used with any Product, as well as publicly released screen shots and
>   video content from the Product, in connection with Epic's marketing,
>   advertisement, and promotion of the Unreal® Engine in any and all
>   media without restriction.

Comment: What If I didn't even notify Epic about the production and didn't mention Unreal?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm no lawyer and this is not legal advice. In that case you run the risk of a lawsuit from Epic if your game becomes succesful and they notice you did not fully abide to the EULA you signed by using their software in the first place. But why would you do that? Why claim UE4 as yours if you did not develop it @Amr ?

Comment: Just asking...Because maybe there are some people who do this.